# How to share handlers?

Tags: ansible

[The docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#introduction) says:

> Since handlers are tasks too, you can also include handler files from the ‘handlers:’ section.

What I do, `playbook.yml`:

```
- hosts: all
  handlers:
    - include: handlers.yml
    # - name: h1
      # debug: msg=h1
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=test
      notify: h1
      changed_when: true
```

`handlers.yml`:

```
- name: h1
  debug: msg=h1
```

Then,

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i localhost, -k -e ansible_python_interpreter=python2 -v
...
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
...
```

But when I uncomment the lines, I see

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i localhost, -k -e ansible_python_interpreter=python2 -v
...
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [h1] ***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "h1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
...
```

I'm running `ansible-2.1.0.0`.

What am I doing wrong? That's **the first thing** I'd like to know. Workarounds come second.

**UPD**

> Includes can also be used in the ‘handlers’ section, for instance, if you want to define how to restart apache, you only have to do that once for all of your playbooks. You might make a handlers.yml that looks like:
>
> ```
> ---
> # this might be in a file like handlers/handlers.yml
> - name: restart apache
>   service: name=apache state=restarted
> ```
>
> And in your main playbook file, just include it like so, at the bottom of a play:
>
> ```
> handlers:
>   - include: handlers/handlers.yml
> ```

Comment: It tells you could include a handlers file in your tasks section (because the handlers file holds a collection of tasks). It does not tell you can use includes in the handlers section. The include itself is a (unnamed) handler and it will not include anything because it never was notified.

Comment: What is your goal? Handlers are global. You do not need to explicitly share them among roles. Include a role with handlers and you can notify them from anywhere.

Comment: See my updated question. The goal is to not repeat handlers throughout my playbook. It has multiple plays. I don't have roles yet.

Comment: Interesting. Ansible is full of strange stuff. This looks like this bug here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15399 I tested this and it indeed used to work in Ansible 1.x and does not in any of the 2.x releases. Furthermore interesting, it appears to actually work in the devel branch, even though there is no comment on the ticket that this has been worked on. Maybe it got fixed while they worked on something else.

Comment: Something else that I noticed is, even with your `changed_when: true` on the debug task, the task is not marked as `changed`, but only is `ok`. Again, this only happens in any of the 2.x releases. In 1.x it is marked as changed. Though this is not the issue. Even when it is not marked as changed in the output, handlers (not implemented per include) get fired in 2.x. Again, Ansible is full of strange stuff... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To moderators. Read my question carefully please. That's the answer to my question. And I'm totally aware that SO is not a forum.*

That's [a bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15399) in `ansible-2.1`. The credit goes to [udondan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188717/how-to-share-handlers#comment63818634_38188717) who found the issue.

Answer (score 19):

Depending on the size of your plays a better solution might be to use roles. Ansible has [some discussion why roles are a good idea](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html).

Tasks go in `roles/mystuff/tasks/main.yml` and `roles/somethingelse/tasks/main.yml`. You can share handlers between the roles, by creating a role containing only handlers `roles/myhandlers/handlers/main.yml` and **make both roles depend on the myhandlers role**:

`roles/mystuff/meta/main.yml` and `roles/somethingelse/meta/main.yml`:

```
---

dependencies:
  - myhandlers
```

More on dependencies in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-role-dependencies